# Pass an input box value through to a var in the js doc to be used

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

Is it possible to pass the value of an input from a form into a var to be used in a function.

for example:

```
<input type="text" id="userID" name="userID" placeholder="Enter user ID" style="width:200px;" />

<input type="submit" value="search" />
```

So the userID would be passed into :

```
 var userId = null;
```

I am looking to use this as a way for a user to input their userID in to the flickr api call.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&getSizes&api_key=feb7e93d9a90e9a734787bea9be81440&user_id='+userID+'&has_geo=1&extras=geo&format=json&jsoncallback=?', mapImages);
```

I had a look around and came across

```
var userId = document.getElementById("userID").value;
```

This does not seem to be working though.

---

I have tried:

```
<form type="post" onsubmit="loadImages(); return false;">

<input type="text" id="userID" name="userID" placeholder="Load user images"  />
<input type="submit" value="Get Flickr images!" />

</form>
```

Using the function:

```
  function loadImages()
  {

        var userId = document.getElementById("userID").value;

  }
```

Is this along the right track or totally off?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is case-sensitive.

In your HTML you use `"userID"` and in your JavaScript `"userId"`.

Comment: I gave that a try, still no joy though.

Comment: When do you assign the userId veriable?  If you do it when the page loads, then it will be empty.  You need to make sure the assignment happens AFTER the user has entered something.

Comment: I had it just at the start of the doc.ready. Should it be placed in a function thats called on submit?

Comment: Could you provide an example of this please. I have been trying what you said but without any luck. I will add above what I have tried. Im not sure if its correct @stepan